# Manipulating User IDs in AD with c#

Tags: c#

I am seriously confused, I'm a very out of practice software engineer (Last job in the field was 1993!) doing a bit of minor coding to make my sysadmin job go easier. I've picked c# over powershell because of its better debugging. What I'm trying to do, is take a username out of a spreadsheet, if that username exists in Active Directory, check its expiry date and if the one in the spreadsheet is later than the one set in active directory then update active directory to reflect.

I'm using VS 2015 on X64 2012 Server
I've got the following segment of code

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement AuthenticablePrincipal.AccountExpirationDate
```

foundUser is the `AuthenticablePrincipal`

`Globals.Uservars` is a global (I know... please no lectures about global variables) String Array holding data which relates to the AD user object.

`Uservars[4]` is the expiry date from the spreadsheet.

`Uservars[7]` is a feedback comment result of operation.

```
AccountExpires = foundUser.AccountExpirationDate.Value.ToLocalTime();
ThisDay = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(Globals.UserVars[4]));
if (ThisDay!=null)
{
   if (ThisDay > AccountExpires)
   {
       foundUser.AccountExpirationDate = ThisDay; 
       foundUser.Save();
       Globals.UserVars[7] = "Account End Date Incremented";
       OutputResult();
   }
   else
   {
       Globals.UserVars[7] = "Existing User No Changes Made";
       OutputResult();
   }
}`
```

My confusion stems from the fact that I don't get an error, if I subsequently read the value of `foundUser.AccountExpirationDate.Value.ToLocalTime();` from AD it has updated with the value from the spreadsheet, If I re-run the program this new value is in place but the flippin' thing doesn't show as changed in active directory users and computers.

Also If I try to convert DateTime values to FILETIME before updating AD (which I believe I should do, as I suspect I'm actually updating AD with an incorrect value despite what I see if I read it back) it seems to throw an error.
DUH?